# android NDK. libzip stopped to sub folder

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-assets, libzip

I use `libzip` to read APK content in native code.

`assets/sounds/voice` folder "disappeared" for libzip functions only.

- `libzip` still see other files.
- I still can see it in `assets/sounds/voice` in project folder.
- I did `clean` many times.
- I still can unzip `APK` file from `bin` folder and I see all required files. (including files from `assets/sounds/voice` folder)

I added small logging command and it does not print files from `assets/sounds/voice` folder. All other files are present.

```
int inum = zip_get_num_files(apkzip);
for(int i = 0; i < inum; i++){
  const char * name = zip_get_name(apkzip, i, 0);
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"FILEZIP", "zip: %s", name);
}
```

I have no idea what at what step it is wrong. Had eclipse compressed ZPK with new format that my libzip does not able to read? or what could be a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an answer for libzip, but why you have to use libzip to read apk file in NDK application? In Android NDK, you can use AAsset APIs to get file from the apk. Take a look at "[How To Get File In Assets From Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317651/629118)".

**EDITED**

> It is not available in android-5 that I still use

Ok. So how about [Cocos2d-x's ZipFile](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/tree/master/cocos2dx/support/zip_support)? It is based on [Minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html).

How to use ZipFile from [cocos2dx/platform/android/CCFileUtilsAndroid.cpp](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/cocos2dx/platform/android/CCFileUtilsAndroid.cpp)

```
s_pZipFile = new ZipFile(resourcePath, "assets/");
pData = s_pZipFile->getFileData(fullPath.c_str(), pSize);
```

Comment: It is not available in android-5 that I still use. When I started project 1.5 year ago it was important.