# NDK c++ load shaders from file Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am a bit confused about filesystem in Android from ndk's perspective. 
I am building it with custom ant files. All I want for now is to read some text files containing my shaders.
As far as I understand:

- Assets are files < 1Mb which can be accessed in plain text form, but not via url or filepaths . I've found on the Internet that it is better to use gradle (like in android studio) to use assets.
- Resources (res directory) can be accessed via url, but in packed form (one have to extract from them like from .zip)

So I decided to use assets. Where should I put my assets folder? All examples I've found were relative to AndroidStudio (src/main/assets) but I use src/com/normalpackage/sources.java and jni/sources.cpp

I even think about creating a program which will take my assets directory as input and on the output I will get a .hpp file containing:

`struct MyFile{
    uchar* filepath;
    uchar* data;
    ...
};`

`MyFile f1(filepath,data1)
MyFile f2(filepath,data2)
...
//or put it in std::map or something`

(packed in data structures, ready to compile it with source code)
I think that it won't be a good solution due to increased compile time (in future I would like to import not only shaders, but also images or audio), but I am might be wrong here (what do you think?).

So, what should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

From the NDK you can use `AAsset_read` to access the assets folder, and I think this will be the best way. You can look here for an example: [How To Get File In Assets From Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317387/how-to-get-file-in-assets-from-android-ndk)

Comment: But where should I put assets folder? All tutorials are refering to src/main/assets, but it is connected with Android Studio gradle building system

Comment: According to the documentation of AAssetManager_open: "To open the top-level directory, pass in "" as the dirName". So I think it will open the default location. Anyway, you can simply try...